# Lollipop - Apps not autostarting

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot, services

I have Alcatel 5054D with Lollipop (5.1.1) on board. I noticed that some apps are not starting on boot or on events that are fired by the OS. For example, when my phone was not rooted I tried to install Truecaller, Truemessenger and Textra. They simply didn't work just after reboot or if I removed them from the recent apps list. What is worse SMS apps won't start on new incoming SMS, the message just disappears without any reaction from Textra or Truemessenger. But everything works fine when I start these apps manually and keep them in the background.

Then I rooted my phone, installed Link2SD and noticed that it fails to start after a reboot too! I have to launch it manually for the paths to be rebinded.
I installed autostarts manager and it showed that all the events (receivers) for these apps are enabled.

On the other hand standard SMS app, Whatsapp, Viber, GMail do autostart and work properly.

I have no task killers installed and cannot figure out the reason of the issue.

Comment: Could it be all the apps which are not working are installed on SD card – while those which do work are not?

Comment: No, they are installed in the phone memory.

Comment: OK, then it's something different. To get a clue (possibly at least), you could [check the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) directly after/during a startup. Watch out for the "E" (errors) and "W" (warnings) lines especially.

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken when I wrote that I have no task killers. It happened so that Lollipop has a built-in task killer feature called "Limited apps" that limits app execution in background. For some strange reason all SMS apps become limited by default. The feature can be found in settings under Applications item.