# Startup apps not running at start up

Tags: boot, lenovo

I've recently purchased a Lenovo Vibe K5 mobile.  The phone runs Android 5.1 Lollipop with the Lenovo UI layered on top.

I have been facing a strange problem.  Apps that are set to start at startup simply don't start until I start them manually.  This includes messaging apps like Telegram etc. (only WhatsApp somehow seems to startup, but it then often hangs), battery monitors, QualityTime, Resilio Sync, Twilight, etc.

This has become more than an annoyance as the failure to start messaging apps means I never receive messages.  I've missed several important messages as a result.

I have checked in Bootup Manager and all these apps are listed as startup apps.  I have also switched off Lenovo's "Intelligent power settings" system (which seems to basically terminate apps if they are running in the background).

I have made no modifications to the stock ROM except rooting it.  I also experienced a weird problem with SMS not being received when I restored messages from a different phone from a backup.  I eventually deleted the message database and started from scratch; that seems to have fixed the problem.

Is there any way to fix this problem?  Where would I start? I am tempted to go the whole hog and replace the stock firmware with a custom ROM, but that is likely to bring its own problems in its wake.  Is that the only route forward?

Comment: This person claimed to have found a solution - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135870/lollipop-apps-not-autostarting - but I cannot locate the setting he's referring to, and that sounds like something from a custom UI rather than stock Android...

Answer (score 2):

In my case it appears that the problem was that some of these apps had been set to "restrict to launch" (in Settings -> Apps -> [each app]).  I don't know what this setting is intended to do, or why it was turned on. Also this does not seem to be a complete solution, but it appears to have ensured that some of them are now starting at startup.

This setting appears to be unique to Lenovo phones, though I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Mine isn't a Lenovo, its an Alcatel, although I'd think since they both run Lollipop 5.1, any differences would be superficial.

Comment: Also, apparently that setting is part of Lollipop, not the Lenovo UI...I've seen that setting in my phone and actually changed which apps were restricted, but it didn't seem to do anything other than make the restricted apps unable to run in the background. I couldn't really tell if it couldn't tell if it affected which apps booted @ startup, but I'll pay closer attention...Thanks!!